# CSS based on data-name?

Tags: html, css, member

Is it possible to style an html element (div) by its data member f.e. data-name?

my div:

```
<div data-name="random_name">...</div>
```

And is it possible to grab the element by data member that contains certain phrase?

f.e. i want to grab and style every element that its data member contains:

```
random*
```

Comment: 'div[data-name="random_name"] {color:red;}

Comment: Thank you and I'm sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use below

```css
div[data-name="random_name"] {border:1px solid red;padding:10px;}
```

```html
<div data-name="random_name">Random name</div>
```